# Python list comprehensions/ loop for selecting same member in different df columns

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I am very new in Python and I have the following problem.

I have a couple of questions that I have found quite difficult to solve by myself.

Suppose we have two pandas data frames, from which I can extract two columns.
Say that in one column, called col1, we have names of subjects, which can be reiterated along the same column, in the following form: 'QUENTIN TARANTINO' or 'Tarantino Quentin'. In the other column, col2, I have entries of the following form: 'TARANTINO, QUENTIN' or 'Tarantino, Quentin', which can be reiterated as well.

Obviously, 'TARANTINO, QUENTIN' or 'Tarantino, Quentin' are the same subject, but are different objects!

I would like to 'merge' these two columns in one column so that the same subject has one and only one label. How can I make it using a list comprehension (or loop) so that it reports both the names (in this form: 'TARANTINO, QUENTIN') and the counts of them?

```
col1 = ['QUENTIN TARANTINO', 'BARACK OBAMA', 'QUENTIN TARANTINO', 'CHARLIE CHAPLIN', 'JAMES LEBRON', 'KOBE BRYANT', 'Philippe Wain', 'LE CAM ALBERT', 'ANDREW ROBERTS', 'Obama Barack', 'tarantino quentin']

col2 = ['OBAMA, BARACK', 'CHAIN, GEORGE', 'Phylo, SOPY', 'Losan, Santos']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Espoir's answer, to take care of flips, run this:

```
col = list(set( [x.lower().replace(', ',' ') for x in col1]+[x.lower().replace(', ',' ') for x in col2])) #thanks espoir
for x in col:
    rev = [i for i in reversed(x.split())]
    if ' '.join(rev) in col:
        col.pop(col.index(x))
```

It will eliminate flipped repeats in col.

For what it does,

1. iterate over col.

   1. generate a reversed list of each name.
   2. check if the joined reversed name is already existing.

      1. if it is, remove it from the list

[`reversed(list)`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_reverse.htm) will return an iterator, so it should be the subject of a for loop. `rev` just keeps a copy of the flipped name for easy comparison in the next step.

Comment: Would you mind explaining to me (a learner) what does rev create? and .join(rev)? Sorry bothering you on this issue

Comment: thanks @notcompletelyrational , upvote my answer for the help it gave to you, please

Comment: Brilliant explanation! You deserve the vote but also thanks to @EspoirMurhabazi for his intuition.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to solve this this is to use set try this : 
as you need to apply lower to all element in your list first

```
col = list(set( [x.lower().replace(', ',' ') for x in col1]+[x.lower().replace(', ',' ') for x in col2]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it does not answer to my question. This create a new column with N1 + N2 elements. I need, instead, a new column with no repeated elements. Cheers

Comment: Exactly: 'QUENTIN TARANTINO' and 'Tarantino Quentin' from col1 represent the same person, and I would like the new column to consider them as the same object, as well as 'TARANTINO, QUENTIN' from col2

Comment: yes but 'quentin tarantino' and 'tarantino quentin ' are still the same subject but are counted as different. Am I wrong?

Comment: yes I see. do you also mean that 'obama barack' and 'barack obama' are the same thing?? if yes set will not solve the problem, let me check for the other way

Comment: yes indeed! Your point helps really a lot but not solve the problem